# Deriving variance for running statistics

Tags: statistics, variance, signal-processing, standard-deviation

From the definition of the variance:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}(x_i-\mu)^2 \tag{1}$$

and mean:

$$\mu = \frac{1}{N}\sum^{N-1}_{i=0}x_i \tag{2}$$

how is it possible to derive the variance for running statistics, which is:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum^{N-1}_{i=0}x_i^2-\frac{1}{N}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i \right)^2\right] \tag{3}$$

why the term $2x_i\mu$ is not considered?

Starting from $(1)$, I get:

$$\sigma^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum^{N-1}_{i=0}x_i^2-\sum_{i=0}^{N-1}2x_i \mu\right]+\frac{\mu^2}{N-1} $$

Comment: A slight issue: For an iid sample sized $N$ you have  $s^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}(x_i-\bar x)^2$ is an unbiased estimator of $\sigma^2$.  If you have a population of $n$ with mean $\mu$ then $\sigma^2 =\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}(x_i-\mu)^2$

Comment: Note that $\sum (x_i \bar x) = \bar x \sum x_i = N(\bar x)^2 = \frac1N \left( \sum x_i\right)^2$

Comment: @Henry, thank you for these hints, but still not clear for me, how $-2\mu x_i$ is disappeared.

Comment: Only half of it disappeared, and for an obvious reason; the rest is still there as $-\frac1N \left( \sum x_i\right)^2$.  Could you edit into your question what actually happened when you expanded the square?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it is clearer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should have for the unbiased sample estimator of the variance, using $\bar x=\frac1N\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i$, is $$s^2 = \frac{1}{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}(x_i-\bar x)^2 \\
=\frac{1}{N-1}\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}\left(x_i^2 -2x_i\bar x+\bar x^2 \right) \\ =\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i^2 -2 \sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i\bar x+N\bar x^2 \right]\\ =\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i^2 -2\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i \frac1N\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i+N\frac1N\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i\frac1N\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i \right]\\ =\frac{1}{N-1}\left[\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i^2 -\frac1N\left(\sum\limits_{i=0}^{N-1}x_i\right)^2 \right]$$

Comment: absolutely clear! thank you so much!